# Iterate smartly

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

Hy!
 So , i am trying to compare the files in a folder ( and subfolders ) to check for
duplicates. I have in this moment 2 ArrayList with the same elements and same order in the both of them , I made 2 for loops to compare each element from the first ArrayList with the elements from the second ArrayList , I had a problem comparing let`s say element no. 10 with element no. 10 (  the same path ) but i resolved it by "if(i=j) continue ;" (i and j are the iterators )
 My question is : if let`s say it finds out that element no 4 from first list equal with element no 7 from the second list , when the first iterator will reach the element no 7 it will say that it`s equal with element no 4 from the second one. How do i make the program to skip this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid iterating duplicates by starting the second loop from just after the index of the first:

```
for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j<N; j++){ 
         //do stuff.
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe i did not make myself understood , this is good for i=j but if i have i = 4 equal with j = 10 when it comes on the other side i = 10 and j = 4 , how i can avoid this cause the have the elements ( 4 - 10 equal , and also 10 -4 equal )

Comment: @LES when i = 10, then j starts from 11. So you never have the condition where i=10 and j=4.

Comment: your solution looked too easy so i did not think on it too much , but now  :D it`s another story .. i saw the light at the end of tunnel :)) - thank you